# alternatives to textmarks.com

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

[textmarks.com](http://textmarks.com) allows you to treat a web server like an SMS server, however I don't like their terms of service.  Can you let me know of any decent alternatives?

Comment: As per ariel's reply - to answer that sensibly, we'd need to know what you find objectionable. Otherwise, alternatives may be even less suitable for your scenario...

Comment: I've been using them as a gateway to a web server with scripts on it to access things at my house.  Texting "mykeyword all lights on" to 41411 would turn on all my house lights for instance.  But they have changed their business model and I can't set up a new keywords any more. (Granted, I still have one that still works but I would like to make a new one.)

I don't really care about their T&C, and I don't need to send to a group. I just want to use the gateway to tickle my web server. I've looked around a little and can't find anyone else doing something similar for cheap or free.

Answer (score 0):

Our site, http://tatango.com/ is a great option. Let me know if you have any questions about the site, I'm more than happy to help!